# JavaFX: Is there a way to have automatically synchronized nodes across panes?

Tags: javafx, radio-button

I'm currently migrating elements from a single pane into tabs and a 3 dimensional set of radio buttons should otherwise always be in the same state.

It's a nonissue to update them all in pairs, programmatically, but I was wondering if there was a way that their states could be fundamentally linked, or if there is an event fired when setSelected is called, or anything of the sort.

Also, as I'm using FXML, so I have some notion of using the same id's to possibly allow for this?

Comment: "if there is an event fired when `setSelected` is called": `selected` is a [JavaFX property](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) so you can directly observe it (`radioButton.selectedProperty().addListener(...)`) or bind it (`rb1.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional(rb2.selectedProperty());`). Ids should be unique.

Comment: You could have a look at binding in JavaFX. You can bind the buttons to each other.